# Oracle SQL: How to print rows with its column name together

Tags: sql, oracle

Note: I don't want to use hard coding because I am not planning to.

exaple:

SQL:

```
select * from my_table
```

OUTPUT:

```
Column name: PERSON, AGE, HEIGHT

Row values: Me/PERSON, 15/AGE, 5/HEIGHT
```

Is this possible to print the values together with its column name? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds better done in the client rather than the query.

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, this is a Presentation concern, not a Business Logic concern. Keep the two separate.

Comment: @AlexK.Yeah i know, I just wish I could finish it on the sql before putting it into the Perl script I made, just to make the logic more cleaner.

Comment: @jeff6times7 what? O_O

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible to print the values together with its column name?

Yes. It's possible. Do it like:

```
select PERSON||'/PERSON', AGE||'/AGE', HEIGHT||'/HEIGHT' 
from my_table
```

Comment: I mentioned, No Hard coding.

Comment: Where is hardcoding? Are your column names changing. I hope no. In that case my solution fits your question. If you need something else then please specify.

Comment: Hi XING, yes its changing, but I am following the SOLID principle. I am doing a script on the perl side and on the web site that is build to adopt incase columns are added. I am seeking a neat solution on achieving this. Thanks alot by the way.